# create custom template for 2 different blog category in shopify

Tags: shopify

I am working with shopify, i have 2 different blog type
**1)news** and 
**2)recipe**

Both have same layout, which is coming from `blog.liquid`.
I just want to create new template for blog `recipe`.

I just see demo here with 2 different layout

[recipe](http://www.panateamatcha.com/blogs/recipes)

[blog](http://www.panateamatcha.com/blogs/blog)

Is there any way to do similar like this links?

Answer (score 0):

Shopify documentation found on this link [Create alternate template for pages, products, collections, blogs, or gift cards](https://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/page-specific/store-wide/can-i-create-and-use-an-alternate-template-for-pages-products-collections-or-blogs) provides you with detail steps on creating and using multiple templates.